# Threads and Processes

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

I am trying to revise my Operating System concepts, but I had some confusions. I know that a process is a thread with its own address space.

1) Are deadlocks only caused by threads or processes? (Threads share the process's stack, where as different processes have different stacks).

2) Can a single process cause a deadlock? or does it take more than one process for a deadlock to occur?

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this. If not, please let me know and I will delete the question.

Comment: IMO process isn't a thread with its own address space, it's something like executing environment, which contans resources (data, address space) and executing activities (threads)

Answer (score 2):

Both threads AND processes can get into deadlocks depending on what they are trying to lock. If the resource that they want to lock is a resource that's shared within a process (e.g. critical section), threads can get into deadlock. On the other hand if it's a resource that's shared globally (e.g. named mutex), processes can get into a deadlock. For 2), there must be more than one process involved since more than one process must try to lock (globally) shared resource in order for a deadlock to occur.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in your Question itself. Each Process has a stack and all the threads created by the process share the stack. whenever two threads of the same process request for a resource(data,comm,...) that other threads has a lock to and in-turn waits for a release of other resource then deadlocks occur.


answer:
for **1)**:
threads cause deadlocks within process and process cause deadlocks within parent process (in most situations OS)

for **2)**:
yes a single process can cause deadlocks.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Threads share the address space of the containing process, but each thread has its own private stack.

Comment: Can you give an example of one thread causing a deadlock? Couldn't find it online or think of it. :)